# LeetCode question Path Sum II: Recursive solution bug

Tags: go, recursion, path, tree

I have submitted the below solution for the [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/) in golang and it fails for the base case. I am not able to figure out why it is failing.

```
var answer[][]int

func hasPathSum(root *TreeNode, sum int, path []int){
    if root == nil {
        return
    }
    newPath := append(path, root.Val)
    sum = sum - root.Val
    if root.Left == nil && root.Right == nil && sum == 0 {
        answer = append(answer, newPath)
        fmt.Println(answer)
        return
    }
    if root.Left != nil {
        hasPathSum(root.Left, sum, newPath)
    }
    if root.Right != nil {
        hasPathSum(root.Right, sum, newPath)
    }
    
}

func pathSum(root *TreeNode, sum int) [][]int {
    
    var path []int
    answer = [][]int{}
    hasPathSum(root, sum, path)
    return answer
}
```

And when I avoid declaring `newPath` it passes the base check. Like this:

```
var answer[][]int

func hasPathSum(root *TreeNode, sum int, path []int){
    if root == nil {
        return
    }

    sum = sum - root.Val
    if root.Left == nil && root.Right == nil && sum == 0 {
        answer = append(answer, append(path, root.Val))
        fmt.Println(answer)
        return
    }
    if root.Left != nil {
        hasPathSum(root.Left, sum, append(path, root.Val))
    }
    if root.Right != nil {
        hasPathSum(root.Right, sum, append(path, root.Val))
    }
    
}

func pathSum(root *TreeNode, sum int) [][]int {
    
    var path []int
    answer = [][]int{}
    hasPathSum(root, sum, path)
    return answer
}
```

I am not able to figure out what is the difference between the two solutions. Both solutions are the same from the recursion point of view. Furthermore, a [similar solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/discuss/738875/C%2B%2B-solution-easy-to-understand) in C++ passes all the checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because slices refer to an underlying array, and `append` does not re-allocate a new array if there's space. See https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

That means when you `append(path, root.Val)`, the new slice will sometimes share the backing array with `path`. That can be a problem, for example:

```
if root.Left != nil {
    hasPathSum(root.Left, sum, append(path, root.Val))
}
if root.Right != nil {
    hasPathSum(root.Right, sum, append(path, root.Val))
}
```

Here, both branches may be using the same backing array. That's a problem, because when executing the first `hasPathSum` it may add a slice to `answer`, but the underlying array of that slice may still be used in the second call to `hasPathSum`, which will change its contents.

Both versions of the code have the same problem, but because the second is less likely to cause problems because if `append(path, root.Val)` needs to reallocate, then you get two different copies in the two branches of `hasPathSum`. This means the bug will happen at a lower frequency.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `fmt.Println(answer)`, you'd probably just need to `return` answer.

This'll pass:

```
func pathSum(root *TreeNode, sum int) [][]int {
    var paths [][]int

    if root == nil {
        return paths
    }

    if root.Left == nil && root.Right == nil {
        if sum == root.Val {
            return append(paths, []int{ root.Val })
        }

        return paths
    }

    for _, path := range pathSum(root.Left, sum - root.Val) {
        paths = append(paths, append([]int{ root.Val}, path... ))
    }

    for _, path := range pathSum(root.Right, sum - root.Val) {
        paths = append(paths, append([]int{ root.Val}, path... ))
    }

    return paths
}
```

Here is LeetCode's Java solution with comments:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    
    private void recurseTree(TreeNode node, int remainingSum, List<Integer> pathNodes, List<List<Integer>> pathsList) {
        
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        
        // Add the current node to the path's list
        pathNodes.add(node.val);
        
        // Check if the current node is a leaf and also, if it
        // equals our remaining sum. If it does, we add the path to
        // our list of paths
        if (remainingSum == node.val && node.left == null && node.right == null) {
            pathsList.add(new ArrayList<>(pathNodes));
        } else {
            
            // Else, we will recurse on the left and the right children
            this.recurseTree(node.left, remainingSum - node.val, pathNodes, pathsList);
            this.recurseTree(node.right, remainingSum - node.val, pathNodes, pathsList);
        }
        
        // We need to pop the node once we are done processing ALL of it's
        // subtrees.
        pathNodes.remove(pathNodes.size() - 1);
    }
    
    public List<List<Integer>> pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
        List<List<Integer>> pathsList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> pathNodes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        this.recurseTree(root, sum, pathNodes, pathsList);
        return pathsList;        
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.